# Mode in react native picker not working

Tags: ios, react-native, picker

I want to make a gender selection using picker. but the mode is not working in ios. Im not sure in android.

```
<Picker
  style={{justifyContent: 'center',backgroundColor: 'white'}}
  selectedValue={this.state.gender}
  onValueChange={(gender) => this.setState({ gender })}
  mode='dialog'
>
  <Item label="Male" value="Male" />
  <Item label="Female" value="Female" />
</Picker>
```

[image: It will only become something like this]

Hope anyone could give some suggestion.. 
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`<Picker>`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html) component renders as a `UIPickerView` on iOS - that's what you're seeing there. This picker is rendered in-place rather than in a modal (as is the case on Android) - the `mode` prop you specified only applies to Android.

There are two options: render the picker within something like a [`<Modal>`](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox) or use a different component entirely.

Comment: Thank you.. I will give <Modal> a try again since I already try it but it cover the whole screen even i set height: height / 2

Answer (score 1):

I solved this type of issue by doing like this.

```
import PickerExample from './PickerExample.js';

class Sample extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {gender: '',};
    this.updateGender = this.updateGender.bind(this);
 }
 updateGender(val){
    this.setState({
 gender: val 
},function(){
  alert("callback function as your wish")
});
}
 render(){
 return (
     <PickerExample gender={this.state.gender} updateGender={this.updateGender.bind(this)} />
  );
 }
```

The  PickerExample.js file look like this.

```
export default PickerExample = (props) => {
return (
  <Picker selectedValue = {props.gender} onValueChange = {props.updateGender}>
     <Picker.Item label = "MALE" value ="Male" />
     <Picker.Item label = "Female" value = "female" />
  </Picker>
 );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I use the `.ios.jsx` extension for the iOS specific picker.  Which I code as follows:

```
export const SelectWidget = ({ 
  selectedOption, 
  setSelectedOption, 
  placeholderLabel,
  options
}) => {

  const items = options.map((option) => {
    return <Picker.Item
      key={option.key ?? option.label} 
      label={option.label} 
      value={option.value}
     />;
  });

  return (
    <Picker
      onValueChange={(value) => {
        setSelectedOption(value);
      }}
      placeholder={{
        label: placeholderLabel,
        value: null,
      }}
      selectedValue={selectedOption}
      style={{
        width: '100%', // fill up the width of the device (without this, nothing gets displayed
      }}
      itemStyle={{
        height: 150, // this reduces the height of the selector
        color: colors.text, // if you're in dark mode set this to white.
      }}
    >
      // default item
      <Picker.Item label={placeholderLabel} value={null} />
      {items}
    </Picker>
  );
};
```